# How get blob data from node.js chunk via websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, blob

I wanna get blob data and create one file.
my node.js server use websocket

```
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: http
    ...
});
wsServer.on('request', function(req){
    ...
    conn.on('message', function(msg){
        ...
        fs.stat(filepath, function(err, stats){
            var fileSize = stats.size;
            var offset = 0;
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath, { start: offset, end: fileSize });
            stream.on('data', function(chunk){
                conn.send(chunk);
            });
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

And Client

```
var conn = new WebSocket(...);
var fileReader = new FileReader();
...
conn.onmessage = function(e){
    //what should I do this line?
};
$('#download').click(function(){
    conn.send(filename);
});
```

index.html -> download button -> filename send to server from client
conn.onmessage : e value is this

[image]

and e.data is this

[image]

How can I read blob data and create one file. It is video file.

Comment: So you want to reassemble the file and allow the user to save it?

Comment: Yeah, I want reassemble the video file by chunk, and download to client computer via browser

Comment: Well you can add the blobs together `bigblob = new Blob([bigblob,e.data],{type: bigblob.type});`. Then make a blob url to initiate a download.

Comment: Thx Musa. It's works! great.